# Delete .jar in java build path or change path from E: to F:

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, windows

I'm working on a Java project on a Windows 10 laptop in which I added external archives. I located my workspace on a USB-stick.
This works fine on my laptop.

On my Windows 10 PC, I get the following error:

```
Project '' is missing required library: 'E:\jar.jar'
```

`E:\` is a disk-drive on my PC.

Now I tried to add the same external archive again, but that does not solve it. I want to either delete the path-reference or move it, so it works again.

I also work on this project on Linux, but I don't program on the same workspace (I copy and paste the code between them) and I know that on Linux you mount a USB-stick like a CD, which may also have caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Project => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Add JAR ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my probem, this is how:

under build path - configure build path there is libraries which lets u delete the entries.